# Format Date in VB From Web Service

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime

I have a date that comes from a web service in the following format-
    12132013

How can i convert 12132013 to 12/13/2013 (format as shortdatestring).  The following gives me the error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

```
Date.Parse("20131202")
```

Comment: Try ParseExact with the format you want

Comment: First line uses `12132013`, but the code sample shows `20131202`. Those are different formats. Which one is your data using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom format. `MMddyyyy` and use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

```
Dim result As Date    
result = Date.ParseExact("12132013", "MMddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can also use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for parsing, which would not raise an exception in case of failed parsing.

For string `"20131202"` use format `yyyyMMdd`, since it appears like year month day

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: using [Date].ParseExact("20131202", "MMddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
 i get a return date of 1/2/2013   (i gave the wrong date format in the question)

Comment: @Chris, then use `yyyyMMdd` format. you can also pass multiple formats to [DateTime.ParseExact overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Got it!  I now see the ucase MM in your response.  Thanks!